# What does "rollback" do when it is for the last revision, followed by a notice about the question being closed?

Tags: support, revisions-list, rollbacks

I watched at the revision page of a question on *Drupal Answers* I edited and voted to close. I noticed the revision page shown this.

[image: screenshot]

What does the rollback link does, in this case? The question was not closed as duplicate, which means the question's body was not edited. Would the question appear as if it has never been closed?

I have now edited the question, but before I did it, that was what the revision page shown at the top.

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: See the question.

Comment: You mean to ask if the rollback is going to reopen the question?

Comment: Or do you mean to ask if the possible duplicate message at the top would be removed, if it was closed as a duplicate and rolled back to a previous revision?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I am asking what the rollback link would do, as that was the latest revision, before the question was closed.

Comment: @bfavaretto The question was not closed as duplicate; if it were closed as duplicate, there would be a revision more (the one done from the Community user that adds the notice about the duplicated question). In this case, there were no other revision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having just *tried this myself*:

1. Created question
2. Closed it
3. Wait 5 minutes for the grace period then make an edit
4. Attempted to rollback to first revision (*before close*)

[image: Screenshot to show reverting to revision before closure]

When the rollback was confirmed, the revisions page refreshed to show the return to the original revision.

[image: Showing I did do the rollback]

As probably expected, **the question remained closed.**

[image: The closure remained in place despite the rollback]

Comment: I think the rollback link will show for anyone that can edit any question or answer (2k+ rep). I'm a 10k user at SO, and I can see the link on closed questions there.

Comment: @bfavaretto ahh yes I can see the link on MSO questions.  Will update answer accordingly, thanks!

Comment: In your case, you had an edit after the question was closed. I am asking what would happen if there were no edit after the question was closed, and you clicked on the rollback link for the revision before the question was closed. In you case, there was text to rollback, but in my case there is no text to rollback. Do you mean the rollback would not have done anything?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I accidentally did this whilst setting up the demo and assumed that it wasn't what you were interested in - sorry, my fault.  If you click rollback on revision one without there being a revision 2 (only a closure notice) then **the revisions page refreshes to show no changes at all.**