# Rollback link is a bit eager to appear

Tags: bug, revisions-list, rollbacks

> [image]

Errr... that shouldn't happen?

Note that [this has been noticed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143316/223030); that question (an investigation into what on earth that link actually does) [indicates that it doesn't really do anything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143316/223030#comment407260_143320):

> If you click rollback on revision one without there being a revision 2 (only a closure notice) then **the revisions page refreshes to show no changes at all.**

So there really is nothing to roll back.